# Images seem cached in browser when tab is not active

Tags: html, image-processing, websocket, html5-canvas

I have written an web app that displays jpegs from a usb camera.

The jpegs are displayed via a canvas control and the jpegs are acquired via a websocket.

I have noticed that when the tab is not the active one ie hidden and then I go back to it after some time I find the image stream had halted but after a few seconds I get a deluge of images to the canvas control resulting in fast motion until it has caught up to present footage.

Is there a way to stop this building up at all?

Comment: Sharing the code, so we can see what's wrong, would be useful.

Comment: @gre_gor thanks for your comment. There is a lot of code but this is not the route of the problem. I need to find a way I guess of detecting in Javascript whether my 'app tab' is the active one,  It is a browser issue.  But thanks

Comment: In addition to listening for `focus & blur` events, if you're using `requestAnimationFrame` it acts as a bellweather of whether your tab is currently active. rAF will halt when your tab becomes inactive and will resume when your tab becomes active again.

Comment: @markE I shall look into that - thanks